# Access class functions from another thead?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I have a function in my class that creates a thread and gives it arguments to call a function which is part of that class but since thread procs must be static, I can't access any of the class's members. How can this be done without using a bunch of static members in the cpp file to temporarily give the data to be manipulated, this seems slow.

Heres an example of what I mean:

in cpp file:

```
void myclass::SetNumber(int number)
{
   numberfromclass = number;
}

void ThreadProc(void *arg)
{

   //Can't do this
   myclass::SetNumber((int)arg);
}
```

I can't do that since SetNumber would have to be static, but I instance my class a lot so that won't work.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you specify the address of the object of myclass as `arg` type and cast it inside the ThreadProc. But then you'll be blocked on how passing the int argument.

```
void ThreadProc(void *arg)
{
   myclass* obj = reinterpret_cast<myclass*>(arg);
   //Can't do this
   obj->SetNumber(???);
}
```

As you said this is maybe not only a bit slow but it also clutters the code. I would suggest to use [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html) for argument binding and to create the threads in an os independent way (for your own source at least) you could use [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html). Then no need for static methods for your threads.

Now in the C++0x standard, here a [small tutorial](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-2-function-objects-and-arguments.html)

Comment: oh ok, well I'll just pass a struct then where 1 of its members is the self pointer

Comment: yes that could be a solution if you're really against boost usage. Note however that these things are now part of the new C++0x standard supported by major compilers, so it's not exotic to use. They are in a different namespace thought: std instead of boost

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a friendly class with a `static` method for this purpose. It looks much cleaner. Eg:-

```
class FriendClass
{
public:
  static void staticPublicFunc(void* );
};
```

Now befriend the above class in your main class ...

```
class MyClass
{
  friend void FriendClass::staticPublicFunc(void*);
};
```

This should enable you to set the `friend-function` as the `thread-function` and access the class per instance in each thread. Make sure to synchronize your access to data visible across threads.